# css even column length

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS 2 Column layout: Column height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749706/css-2-column-layout-column-height)

I am trying to create 2 columns that are even in length.  I got it to work to an extend, but would like to know how to limit the size of the outer div to the inside content.  This way the outer div re-sizes depend on either columns required length to display all the content within.

Right now my code adds a lot of extra height.

Thanks in advance!

Here is a jsfiddle with my code:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/Bk77A/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't repeat all of you code, but basically you need a clearfix, then set the container height:auto; position:relative.  Also, why do you have soooo much padding and negative margin on your main content?  Get rid of it.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div.... innner divisions that are floated>
    </div... end of all inner divs>
    <div class="clearfix></div> (clearing our floats)
</div> (closing our wrapper)

css:

#wrapper {
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    additional styling
}
.clearfix {
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick, is it possible to get the right column background to extend the entire height of the wrapper, regardless of what inner div requires more height?

Comment: Yeah, see the comment on your question, it is a link to someone that asked this exact same question and was answered perfectly with a link to the best guide ever for that. I would also highly recommend cleaning your code up big time/starting from scratch.  You have a lot of mix and match of inline styling, css sheet styling, and conflicting styling (you gave your sidebar both float left and float right in two different places).

Comment: Yes - I agree.  I looked at the refer to link.  Worked out great.  Again thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this `padding-bottom: 9999px` for both your columns

Comment: Thanks that helped. One last issue, if I add additional lines to the main content (left), the wrapper does not increase in height to display the content.  But if I do this for the right side it does extend the height.  Can I get this to extend the height if either side demands more content viewing area?

Comment: How so? It works for me. Here is the updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Bk77A/1/

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention, that I am trying to get the right background color to extend to the bottom of the outer div even when the main content is longer than the right content.

Comment: That's more complicated and you have 2 ways of doing that. 1. Like here http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks 2. Position absolute the right column and set `top:0; bottom:0;`

Comment: I gave refer link way before him, yet he gets the right answer. Cool dude, happy posting to stack!